# Display an icon as per file type

Tags: php, html, laravel

What is the best way to display an icon according to the file type in front end document listing? The file type can be any type.

I am planning to try this:

```
public function getIconAttribute() {

    $extensions = [
        'jpg' => 'jpeg.png',
        'png' => 'png.png',
        'pdf' => 'pdfdocument.png',
        'doc' => 'wordicon.jpg',
    ];

    return array_get($extensions,$this->extension,'unknown.png');
}
```

But I need to specify all file types manually. Is there any better way to do this in php/laravel?

Comment: All file types in the world?

Comment: well you need an image per file type anyways, so you need to do it manually.

Comment: Yeah, am also thinking  we need to restrict the user to upload the specified files only then we can check it manually in front end right?

Comment: You should restrict users to upload specified files, because you don't know what filetype they trying to upload, that you show an icon for it!

Comment: Great !Thank you..

Comment: Definitely take a look into the upload mechanism as that probably is the main issue here. This is just a workaround.

Comment: You can simply use an API.
Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69754773/9561654

Answer (score 1):

You could match filenames to extensions, and use a file lookup.

```
public function getIconAttribute() {
    $extension = strtolower($this->extension);

    $rewrite_map = array(
        'jpeg' => 'jpg',
        'docx' => 'doc'
    );

    if(isset($rewrite_map[$extension])) {
        $extension = $rewrite_map[$extension];
    }

    if(file_exists('/path/to/icons/dir/' . $extension . '.png')) {
        return $extension . '.png';
    }

    return 'unknown.png';
}
```

You'll then only need to modify this method if you start supporting another file type with ambiguity in its extension.